# How do I loop through an array of objects using v-for in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js

I'm struggling with iterating through this array of objects. I'm not seeing any console errors and not sure why the data is not displaying.

```
{
 "messages":[
  {
    "id":1,
    "sender":"frank",
    "message":"Lorem ipsum...",
    "time":1398894261,
    "status":"read"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "sender":"mary",
    "message":"Lorem ipsum...",
    "time":1390824261,
    "status":"read"
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "sender":"john",
    "message":"Lorem ipsum...",
    "time":1308744200,
    "status":"unread"
  }
 ]
}
```

I'm using an http get request and the data is coming in, but I can't iterate through it. Here's my js:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: '',
    ready: function() {
      // GET request
      this.$http.get('https://www.example.com/file.json', function (data) {
        // set data on vm
        this.$set('data', data.messages);
        }).error(function (data, status, request) {
            console.log('http request error')
        })
    }
  })
```

And here's my html:

```
<div v-if="data">
  <li v-for="d in data">{{ d.sender }}</li>
</div>
<p>{{data[0].sender}}</p> <!-- this part works -->
```

Comment: First of all redefine messages as an empty array in your data object at the moment of its creation. Instead of $set, simply just assign the data.messages to this.messages, and also use a computed property to extract the messages from the data and iterate through it in the template.

Answer (score 1):

In the callback of AJAX request, `this` is NOT vm, you can solve this by

1. use arrow function
2. use `var vm = this`
3. use `.bind(this)`

this pen use arrow function: https://codepen.io/iampaul83/pen/bYpqgm

`arrow function`:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: '',
    ready: function () {
        // GET request
        this.$http.get('https://www.example.com/file.json', (data) => {
            // set data on vm
            this.$set('data', data.messages);
        }).error(function (data, status, request) {
            console.log('http request error')
        })
    }
})
```

`var vm = this`:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: '',
    ready: function () {
        // GET request
        var vm = this
        this.$http.get('https://www.example.com/file.json', function (data) {
            // set data on vm
            vm.$set('data', data.messages);
        }).error(function (data, status, request) {
            console.log('http request error')
        })
    }
})
```

`.bind(this)`:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: '',
    ready: function () {
        // GET request
        this.$http.get('https://www.example.com/file.json', function (data) {
            // set data on vm
            this.$set('data', data.messages);
        }.bind(this)).error(function (data, status, request) {
            console.log('http request error')
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be due to vue.js deep reactivity limitation.( check vue's documentation )
My suggestion is to use push instead of using 
`this.$set`  loop through your response and push the result one element by one in messages variable which u will declare in your data object.

`data.messages.forEach( (msg ) => { 
     this.messages.push( msg ); 
}`

In your template loop through the messages variable.